# How to tweak Unity panel bgcolor in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: unity, 12.10, panel, colors

Currently in Ubuntu 12.10 we have very few GTK3 themes upgraded to version 3.6 in addition to the default Ambiance theme.

When you maximize an application window, you have only the toolbar below the Unity panel, which assumes the functionality of both title and menubars.
But this may create a problem in some themes where the bgcolor of the Unity panel does not match very well with the bgcolor of the toolbar.

For example, Greybird theme doesn't have this problem, and it has the following code in "unity.css":

```
.unity-panel {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.2)),
                                     to (shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.0)));
```

But another theme has this code in "gtk-apps.css":

```
.unity-panel {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@theme_bg_color, 1.1)),
                                     to (@toolbar_gradient_start));
```

And this produces a unity panel much lighter than the toolbar unlike Greybird. And using Greybird's code or changing the value 1.1 doesn't make any difference.

**The questions is; how can I make the second theme have a Unity panel with a darker grey bgcolor?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that was causing this theme to be **unresponsive to changes** in the values that affect the bgcolor of the unity-panel was apparently (as far as I could figure out by trial-and-error) int the **Gnome Panel section** which was included in the same "gtk-apps.css" file, which was resolved when I deleted this entire section, which was **not needed under Unity** anyway.